# DynamoDB inheritance no mapping parent hash

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have 3 class:

```
public abstract class Animal{
    private String id;
    private String name;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Then a class Cat:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Cat")
public class Cat extends Animal{
    private String purr;
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Purr")
    public String getPurr() {
        return purr;
    }
    public void setPurr(String purr) {
        this.purr = purr;
    }
}
```

And a similar class `Dog` that extends `Animal` and use another table called *Dog*: `@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Dog")`

The problem is that when I try to save a `Cat`, I get the error:

```
Cat: does not map HASH key on model
```

But `Cat` should have the hash key of his superclass.

I can solve moving the annotation: `@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Cat")` from the class `Cat` to the superclass, it works to save `Cat`. I still have not tested if this will cause problem to `Dog`, but I don't think so, because it will be overwrited by  `@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Dog")`

But this solution seem ugly to me. Is there a nicer solution? (I would consider to merge both the tables Dog and Cat to just one table called Animal.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put this annotation on superclass:

```
@DynamoDBDocument
public abstract class Animal{
//...
}
```